# Use outputs of multiline run commands in GITHUB actions

Tags: github-actions, schema.yml

I want to run multiple run commands, but also use the output of each line, as an input to next line.

Something like this.

```
- name: Upload to firebase and increment git tag
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    run: |
      //I want to save these outputs
      VERSION_NAME=$(./gradlew -q getVersionName -Pflavour="myapp" | tail -n 1)
      LATEST_TAG=$(git tag --list --sort=-version:refname "myapp/v*-snapshot.*" | head -n 1)
      CHANGE_LOG=$(bundle exec fastlane changelog tag:$LATEST_TAG)

      // Use the above outputs here
      ./gradlew -PversionCode=$((1000 + $GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER)) -PchangeLog=$CHANGE_LOG assembleRelease appDistributionUploadRelease
      bundle exec fastlane increment_git_tag app_name:'myapp' tag_type:'snapshot' version_name:$VERSION_NAME build_number:$((1000 + $GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER))
```

The above works when I run the commands directly from a macOS terminal(line-by-line). But when I run the GITHUB action, it does not seems to save the output or makeuse of it in the actual referring line(s).

Comment: Did you check each variable value before using it? What you did should work fine if all the tools and variables are set correctly in the workflow file.

Comment: Do I need to echo each variable before I could make use of it?. The workflow is setup fine. Because if I pass the values directly it is working fine. But when I do this way, I somehow get the fields values as always empty.

Comment: According to what I tested [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester43.yml) ([output](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/7111233105?check_suite_focus=true)), the issue might be related to the `actions/checkout`. How did you configure it? For example, if you don't inform the `fetch-depth: 0`, you won't be able to retrieve the tag from the `git tag --list` command in the workflow run.